# What would be the best format for multiple data entry?

Tags: csv, data-entry

For example i would like to input a list of students into a database, can you suggest any formatted csv file or excel?.. what would be the best?..any suggestions would be appreciated! thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

There are far more libraries available for a wider range of languages to work with CSV than Excel files, so if those are the only two choices, I'd strongly suggest CSV.

But if you're putting them into a database, you could probably write a nice tool to either prompt a human to enter all the data into a database, or scrape an existing source of student information to push into the database. I mean, the whole point of having the database is so you can write queries, so might as well write some tools for putting data *in* too. :)